# Is it possible to "wake up" linux kernel process from user space without system call?

Tags: system, kernel, call, real-time, ioctl

I'm trying to modify a kernel module that manages a special hardware.
The user space process, performs 2 ioctl() system calls per milliseconds to talk with the module. This doesn't meet my real.time requirements because the 2 syscalls sometimes take to long to execute and go out my time slot.
I know that with mmap I could share a memory area, and this is great, but how can I synchronize the data exchange with the module without ioctl() ?

Comment: Tell us more about the hardware and its requirements. The correct solution is going to be *very* specific to the details of your hardware timing requirements, software processing requirements, how much control you have over what else the platform is doing (general purpose? embedded? quasi-dedicated server only?), and so on.

Comment: The hardware I use is a generic PC. it installs a card that runs a CANopen communication bus.
CANopen-card module triggers the exchange of information with the process at the time of my user space ioctl().
The operating system is Linux with realtime patches. So I have high control on the execution time of the user space code.
My problem is just when I run the ioctl(), in that moment it break the bonds of my realtime kernel.

Comment: If you really need a user-space process to stop executing for just a millisecond or so and then resume, you shouldn't de-schedule it. Just spin in the kernel. You can't usefully schedule another process and then pre-empt it a millisecond or two later. It's a losing proposition.